# Python script delete objects

Tags: python, scripting

I have a python script that (amongst other things) is supposed to delete objects.
Currently I am unlinking the object but when I want to create objects later in the script with the same name as the deleted it is automatically named name.001 and so on.
Is there a way to completely delete objects using a script?

Comment: Can remove object from the collection (`bpy.objects.remove(ob)`) after unlinking.  However a simple, and perhaps safer,  workaround is to rename object (eg `ob.name = "delete_me"`)  before unlinking from scene, and let blender take care of removal if ob has zero users on save / reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bpy.data.objects.remove(bpy.context.scene.objects[id], do_unlink = True)
```

This should remove unlink the object from every scene you have. After that, the creation of a new object should go without the namechange.